# Lubuntu 18.04 enormous RAM consumption

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, ram, memory-leak

I am a fresh Lubuntu user looking for a way to work on a relatively old PC with 4 GB of RAM with more than 50 tabs opened in a web browser.

Whenever I start the OS and open let's say something like 40 tabs, the sysmonitor shows that approximately 1.3 GB of RAM is being used. I consider this amount of system memory being used perfectly normal.

But as I continue working with the OS, like browsing internet or using GIMP or whatever else, I usually start experiencing some weird problems with a lack of RAM. Needless to mention that I have multiple WEBCONTENT threads obviously generated by FF itself but here is the thing: If I completely close FF, they will still be there! I can kill a few processes manually, but first of all this is just not the way it's all supposed to be and second I can free up only around 100-200 MB of RAM. Where does all the other memory go??

Same happens to Skype, GIMP and qtorrent. After I close these apps I have to kill each and every process manually which is once again just a pure nonsense.

I did some research and found out that it's been obviously only me and my RAM problem with Lubuntu and nobody else seems having it other than me.

Could anyone make an educated guess on what could be wrong?

UPD: here is an output of `inxi`command in .abw format: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BQPAJryAycibpNxQX4ukOE5e1CfjXBNN

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GgCykqZJTxXhXboH9282Su2_Fi7BOsy- these are screenshots of `top` command

Comment: What's the parent of these extra memory-using processes, checked with (for example) `px auxf`? Which web browser are you using (firefox?) and is it up to date? Consider trying a different one? Or the newer versions are apparently different, maybe try an LTS version? If it's every program then it sounds like a bug (lubuntu?), tried XFCE?

Comment: Each DEsktop has libs that use memory; you mention programs that use different libs because they are for different DEs. eg. Gimp uses GTK+3 (Gnome..), qtorrent uses Qt (KDE, LXQt..), let alone others... Each cause your system to load required libraries to function & don't use the GTK+(2) libs in memory thus are inefficient. You may actually be better using a heaver DE where you can stick to programs that use libraries already in memory.  Do your "memory calculations" take this into account?  (you don't mention which Lubuntu where the significance will vary [esp. due to non-LXDE apps]

Comment: Install `inxi` and then post the output from `inxi -Fxxxzr` here so that people have some specific data to look at. Also, you've been asked to provide your browser version; what about browser extensions? As it stands your question is incomplete.

Comment: @guiverc Well first of all - thank you all guys that you are paying attention with my problem as I keep growing in desperation with that RAM problem. I really liked this Lubuntu 18.04 I\m currently using and I don't think I will go back to Windows for quite a long period of time.

Comment: So @guiverc I didn't get everything you've mentioned but let me ask you if I got a few basic things right. 1. Are you saying different apps cause different dependencies (i.e libraries) to load any time I call the app itself? Well it's totally fine by me in that case. GIMP take up only somewhat around 100mbs of RAM when it's running (100 mbs!!! Fantastic!!) and therefore I don't consider this as a problem.

Comment: But the thing is after I close any of those apps they should be _unloaded_ out of the RAM automatically shouldn't they? Do I have to manually search for every hidden process and kill it clicking a mouse button or using a terminal?? That doesn't feel all right to me at all!!! Feels just like manually starting an auto engine a hundred years ago!
Just a quick example: any time I start a fresh os with a FF browser (40+), GIMP, 3-4 pcman (file explorer) windows it only takes up around 1.3gb of RAM which is a totally AWESOME result by me.

Comment: I'm not even trying to complain about this - honestly this is exactly the reason why I want to give that Lubuntu system a try so much. 
The problem is that after some time it actually takes all the rest of the memory and this is just not right. So no matter which libraries I use but GTK+(2), QT or GTK+3 - they should be *UNLOADED* from the system memory, shouldn't they?

Comment: Furthermore as being a new user to Linux environment I can't really see all the difference between QT, LXQT or KDE. I just realized I should learn more about the differences and at the same time my intuition is telling me that KDE should be really heave, GNOME - somewhat lighter and QT or LXQT should be the options I was really looking for.

Comment: So regarding your question if my memory calculations took that into account - the answer is "NO" - I didn't even make any of those calculations just because I can't really tell which app uses which library! (Btw can you enlighten me  a little bit on this one - how can I know which libraries the app uses and which libraries should I stick with??)

Comment: @guiverc And regarding your answer as about going with some heavier DE that already contains in memory RAM most of the software I need - that is a smart move and probably I should try to pull this one trick too but which DE should I start with? Can you give me any of your suggestions on that one? 
guiverc And again thanks for your responsiveness!

Comment: @Xen2050  Xen, thanks for your fast reply! 
1. Well I'm terribly sorry I don't think I can be a lot of help for you since I'm being a truly 'fresh meat' with the world of Linux. I tried to run `px auxf` in Terminal but everything I got was "px: command not found". Also I don't really think I could be a lot of help with all those parent extra-memory using processes and in the first place just because I have no clear idea what processes do that. Would be real nice if you'd recommended me a few tools to get a bit more aware with my memory consumtion (I tried to install ATOP app but failed).

Comment: @Xen2050  Yes, Xen, I tried other browsers like Crome, Chromium, some default "WEB", Xombrero and opera installation didn't work quite well for me. At first I was thinking it was totally FF to blame but then I realized I have all those unloaded processes in RAM with Skype and other different apps so maybe it's not FF to blame. So I currenly I'm totally pleased with the way my FF runs and I have no complaints about it.

Comment: @Xen2050 I didn't quite get it... About the newer version... Newer LTS version of FF? I didn't even know they exist!
As long as I understand XFCE - name of the different DE? Well I chose Lubuntu for the reason of it's lightweight and honestly speaking I would stick to it as it does exactly what I want. I could've tried to switch to Xubuntu (which is Already installed on other old PC) but I'm just trying to make it work for my with current setup.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DK Bose 
Sure, I'll try to provide them a bit later.
Tnx for your attention!

Comment: Try `ps auxf`, not `px auxf` which was a typo.

Comment: Please open a terminal emulator and run `COLUMNS=132 top -b -c -n 1 -o '%MEM' | head -22` and edit the question to show the results. (This will show the 15 processes which use most memory, plus some other memory usage and performance indicators.)

Comment: Actually, how do you know your ram usage is unusually high? If you're counting buffers/cache too it's instantly free-able for programs, see `free` & it's used column, or clear with `echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`. Firefox has a few different versions, the LTS is an older one patched, or a newer one direct from mozilla.org or a later/testing ubuntu or debian. [It was `ps`, not px, typo oops ;-] And `top` & `htop` might help, but I'd try live versions of other distros (xubuntu, LTS ubuntu/xubuntu, other xfce-based linuxes, etc) and see if their ram usage seems different.

Comment: @AlexP Hi I guess I just added some screenshots and `inxi` output hope that will come in handy.

Comment: @Xen2050 all that sounds to much complicated to me. I guess I better stick to Windows back again.

Comment: It's too hard to try different live USB's/ISO's? Or too hard to understand what free ram really is in Linux (or even run one echo command & check again)? Both have dozens of good answers from any web search, and I'm sure have been answered here before, you should probably delete this question if it won't help and will never really be answered.

Comment: @Xen2050 clearly answers like yours are the best motivation to get back to Windows family OS.

Comment: can't access those files you attached. Please copy text into your question (format as code) and add images by pressing the add image button. Someone will fix the links to display images for you

Comment: @Zanna Deal. I'll try that a bit later.

Comment: @Zanna Actually they work I just've checked them out. You should download them first.

Comment: Single_Mode it's unreasonable to ask people to download random stuff uploaded by a stranger. Please make the information available in an appropriate way